# AutoMapper throws intermittent exceptions (with SimpleInjector use)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

When the service starts up and calls `Mapper.CreateMap<T, T2>();` we sometimes get the following error being thrown intermittently:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   System.NullReferenceException (-2147467261)
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   at AutoMapper.TypeMapFactory.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(IMemberConfiguration _)
>   The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type T failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is fixed in Visual Studio or the deployment server by redeploying/retrying; it would seem that there is a problem with the AutoMapper library. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're using an older version, upgrade.

Comment: We're currently using 4.1, the newest is 9.0.0; I guess that could be a reason

Comment: Whatever issues that version might have, they're history at this point.

Comment: And if a version upgrade is out of the question due to business restrictions? I have a feeling there's not really much that can be investigated especially as this error looks like it's wrapped in the AutoWrapper library

Comment: @bendev88 what's the restriction in updating it? Yes it does cause a breaking change if you're already having mapping profiles, but it's for the good

Comment: You can always take the source code from GitHub and debug it.

Comment: We can't update it, it's high risk. I guess we could but replicating it would be near impossible

Comment: We figurd out the issue, AutoMapper isn't threadsafe when it's generating the maps; we wrapped the code in a lock and it works.